# Enable libvirt using sysvinit

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt, sysvinit, mx-linux

I am trying to install qemu and KVM on my MX-Linux 21, however my system is booted with sysvinit. As all the articles regarding installing and setting KVM use systemctl, I cannot find one to enable libvirt using sysvinit.

- When I run

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/libvirt start
  ```

  it gives me this output:

  ```
  sudo: /etc/init.d/libvirtd: command not found
  ```
- When I run this command

  ```
  sudo service libvirtd start
  ```

  it shows this output:

  ```
  libvirtd: unrecognized service
  ```

Is there any way to start and enable `libvirt` in `sysvinit`? I know alternatively I can boot with `systemd` and it would sort out the issue, but I am comfortable in `sysvinit` as the default setting of MX-Linux, so I am curious and eager to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Which libvirt version are u using? The sysvinit scripts have been removed since "commit 912fe2df9d Drop support for "Red Hat" init scripts"(https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt/-/commit/912fe2df9d8628b2f3d54485f1cb919cb124d07a). From the commit, maybe you can get libvirt init scripts from previous version or the custom scripts of Gentoo and Alpine.

Comment: Really?  You typed `sudo /etc/init.d/libvirt` *(without a `d` at the end)* and it gave you a message about `/etc/init.d/libvirtd` *(**with** a `d` at the end)*?  If so, please make an explicit statement that you got an error message that doesn’t match the command you typed, because that would be really weird.  If the above is a typo, please fix it. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
sudo apt install libvirt-daemon-system-sysv
```

Answer (score 1):

Run with "...d"

```
sudo /etc/init.d/libvirtd start
Starting libvirt management daemon: libvirtd.
```

Answer (score 0):

If `service` doesn't recognize the service then it's not installed on the system. You can install it with `sudo apt install libvirt-daemon-system`. If you run into further issues check the MX Linux forum, because for some reason it doesn't appear in search results and it likely has all your questions answered.